# How to say "of the" as in "Church of The Blessed Virgin" with the sense of "belonging to" or "patronage"?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, sentence-translation

I would be glad if anyone could help me how to translate the name "Church of the Virgin Mary" or at least how to place "of the" in the sense of "belonging in patronage" in such contexts? Other examples that I would struggle with would be "Covent of the Holy Virgin" or "St John's Covent". Would it be "de" as in "Ecclesia Cathedralis Nostrae Domina **de** Immaculatæ Conceptionis" for such examples?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to do this. One is the earlier usage, from Classical Latin, and the other is the later usage, from Vulgar Latin.

You actually provided an example of both!

> *Ecclesia Cathedralis Nostrae Dominae de Immaculatae Conceptionis*
>   Cathedral **of** Our Lady **of** the Immaculate Conception

The older/Classical way is to use the *genitive case*, a special ending on the possessor. "Our Lady" would normally be *nostra Domina*; "of our Lady" is *nostr**ae** Domin**ae***.

The later/Vulgar way is to use the preposition *de*, which replaced the genitive case in the Romance languages—so it'll look familiar from Italian, Spanish, French, and so on. This isn't good Classical style (in Classical Latin, *de* means "down from" or "concerning", not "of") but it's very common in later Latin. In fact, your example actually uses both together: *immaculatae conceptionis* is in the genitive, *and* it's preceded by *de*.

As a classicist, I prefer the genitive, and I believe the Vatican does as well. Thus, the Church of the Virgin Mary would be ***Ecclesia Virginis Mariae***. Similarly, your other examples would be *Conventus Virginis Beatae*, and *Conventus Sancti Jo[h]annis*.

Comment: I'm almost certain it's *conventus*. Also, would you mind providing an example where *de* is paired with the genitive? I've never seen that before

Comment: @brianpck I'll search for one when I have a corpus available; in the meantime I got rid of the "not uncommon" wording.

Comment: Sounds good. It's worth noting that the OP's example seems to come from a poor translation on a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myeongdong_Cathedral) with at least one obvious mistake (*domina* instead of *dominae*), so I wouldn't trust that as a good example!

Comment: @brianpck Yeah, I feel sure I saw it at some point but that's not exactly a proper citation! I'm going to search when I can.